# Play framework and gradle

Tags: java, gradle, playframework-2.0

I would like to build the play framework with Gradle in a multiproject build.
The play application would be one of my gradle subprojects. The controllers in play, will call methods in my other gradle projects.
Gradle uses sbt by default. Should I just use sbt command line calls in the gradle build file? And if I do that, would I be able to package it as an application (e.g. a jar file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native support for play is currently in the works for Gradle. This is still in development, but you can take a look at some sample projects in the `samples/play` directory of the 'all' distribution of Gradle 2.3.